# Animate accusative for countries

Tags: грамматика

In [*Трава и камни* by Boris Pasternak](https://boris-pasternak.su/stihi-o-prirode/trava-i-kamni) we read:

> С действительностью иллюзию,
> С растительностью гранит
> Так сблизили Польша и Грузия,
> Что это обеих роднит.

I'm surprised by "обеих". I would have expected "обе". Indeed, I believe that "обеих" refers to "Польша и Грузия" and that "обеих" is for the animate accusative. Is it common to use the animate accusative for countries, or is it the case that what would be normal would be "обе," but here, it's a poetic way to anthropomorphize these two countries?

Comment: A very astute observation, by the way, +1

Comment: He uses personification , that's why the case is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the case that what would be normal would be "обе" but here it is a poetic way to anthropomorphize these two countries?

Yes, it is.

Country names are inanimate, and normally, we would say *роднит обе* or *роднит их обе*

The usual test for animacy on a grammatical level in Russian is putting the noun into the plural accusative.

For obvious reasons, it's not always easy with countries, but here are some examples:

> - У меня есть знакомый, инженер-гидротехник, который посетил обе Кореи, его личные впечатления тоже очень интересны.
> - И все же самым любимым занятием было, растянувшись на раскладушке, глотать одну за одной «Черные Индии», «Архипелаги в огне» (о, это полное собрание сочинений Жюля Верна, аккуратные томики, завернутые в синюю бумагу!) и не торопясь листать «Природу и люди» за 1916 год.
>   [Виктор Некрасов. Взгляд и Нечто (1977)]
> - Конечно, в Америке из поколения в поколение передается ностальгия по матушке Европе, и где только возможно американцы строят "маленькие Англии " — и в Диснейленде, и возле трапов "Куин Мэри ", — а также маленькие Италии, Германии, России...
>   [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]

Comment: @CocoPop: animacy in Russian can exist on the grammatical level (_варить креветки / варить креветок_) and on the semantic level (_кого/что ты любишь?_). The idea was to emphasize that it's how you test it on the grammatical level, as opposed to the semantic one.

Comment: The thing is that we normally say *on **a** grammatical level*.

Comment: @CocoPop: thx, fixed